# "'Command.__call__' was never awaited" when trying to execute Discord bot command on Tkinter button click

Tags: python, asynchronous, tkinter, discord.py

I've been trying to create a Discord self bot which posts a message in a specific channel based off a button input on another program. But I receive this error:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine `Command.__call__` was never awaited

How can I solve this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot('', self_bot=True)


@bot.command()
async def on_command():
    channel = bot.get_channel('ID')
    await channel.send('Message')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.configure(background="#161616")

pathBtn = tk.Button(
    root, height=1, width=10, text="Text", background="#282828",
    command=lambda: on_command()
).pack()

spaceLabel = tk.Label(root, text="", height=1, background="#161616").pack()

root.mainloop()
bot.run("TOKEN", bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on_command` is not a function it's `coroutine` see here [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

You should use the `await expression`.